# Copying Modified Date in Window Explorer from Powershell

Tags: library, explorer, powershell

I have the PowerShell script which download Documents from SharePoint Document Library.i want to copy the modified date of documents including folders to the window explorer. Where I am going wrong here?

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$destination = "C:\\Test\\"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://xyz:4444/"
$list = $web.GetList("http://xyz:4444/Shared Documents")
#$site = "http://rssplsp08:9822"


function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
     $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 

        }


    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory



        #Download file
        try
        {

        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
        $exportlist = @()
        $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $spQuery.Folder=$folder;
        $items = $list.GetItems($spQuery);
        $items| foreach {

           $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{

                 "Modified Date" = $_["Modified"]


            }  

                        $a= Get-Item "$destinationfolder"
                        $a.LastWriteTime=$_["Modified"]
        }       



         }
        catch
        {
        #Add-content "c:\log3.txt"  $error
        Write "Error: $file.name: $_" >>c:\logfile.txt
        continue;
        }

        }
}

foreach($folder in $list.RootFolder.SubFolders)
{

if($folder.Name.StartsWith("T") )
{
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)


       if ($folder.Subfolders.Count -gt 0)
        {
            ProcessAllSubfolders($folder.SubFolders)
        }

}
}

function ProcessAllSubfolders($folderCollection)
{
    foreach ($folder in $folderCollection)
    {
        if ($folder.SubFolders.Count -gt 0)
        {
            ProcessAllSubfolders($folder.SubFolders)

        }

        ProcessFolder($folder.Url)

    }
}
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download root files

#Download files in folders
```